# Beacon Scanning not working in Android nougat version

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I have used Altbeacon library for beacon mobile device scanning but its not working but working in Lollipop version.

I am using scanning in foreground and background and code below:

```
 beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(6000);
 beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(6000);
 beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000);
 beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000);
```

Please suggest me for right path.

Thanks

Comment: I have certainly tested the reference app with Nougat with similar settings and found it to detect beacons.  I suggest you try to reproduce with that app , verify it works and then look for differences with your code.

Comment: I have also tested this on Lollipop with no trouble detecting.  Sorry but the question gives not enough info to go on.